# Annotate list of variables in PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

I have a list of objects which I retrieve in the following way:

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $helper->getStuff();
```

except longer.

Now, all of these variables are of the same class, `Foo`, and I want to annotate them so that the IDE (PHPStorm) realizes what I'm doing.

Normally, getting one variable at a time, I would go

```
/**@var Foo $var1 */
$var1 = ...;

/**@var Foo $var2 */
$var2 = ...;
```

etc. But how can I accomplish this, with the `list($var1, $var2, $var3) = ...;` way of getting them?

Ideally, it would be something like

```
/**@var Foo $var1, $var2, $var3 */
```

so that I could consolidate them into one line. And yes, I've tried that, both comma-separated and space-separated.

Comment: The annotation will work in those cases too

Comment: Just curious if you have tried 2016.2.1 (EAP build at the moment)? There is a chance that it is better there (as long as `$helper->getStuff()` has proper `@return` tag annotation). If not -- then it might get improved in 2016.3 version

Comment: @LazyOne - Yeah, one can usually do that with a return tag. However, the `getStuff()` function is annotated with `@return Foo[]` but it doesn't carry over.

Comment: @Alec Accordingly to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-20192 ticket it will be supported/working better in 2016.3 for cases where original variable/function return is an array of objects of specific type (e.g. `Foo[]`)

Comment: @LazyOne - Excellent catch! Looking forward to 2016.3 then!

Comment: @Alec 2016.3 EAP is now available -- please try it: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2016/09/phpstorm-2016-3-early-access-program-started/ If you find it working well (at least for your original case) then I may suggest you to post it as separate answer (no need to accept it instead of current one -- it is just to make it more visible to other users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can place them all in a single block above it. For example:

```
/**
 * @var Foo $var1
 * @var Foo $var2
 * @var Foo $var3
 */
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $helper->getStuff();
```

---

You *can* wedge them all into one line if you use separate blocks, like:

```
/**@var Foo $var1*/ /**@var Foo $var2*/ /**@var Foo $var3*/
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = $helper->getStuff();
```

but I suspect that's not the concise readability you're after.

Comment: That looks more tidy, but is there no way to annotate them all on one line?

Comment: Haha, **A** for effort though! I'll be using the first variant you proposed. :)